# jQuery Table styling with a title

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

I have a jQuery table which renders as below:

[image]

The markup is below.

```
       <table class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 565px; height: 80px; margin-top: 10px;">
        </table>
```

How can I break the table border so that it encloses what the table is about - so I have mocked up in the below Image what I would like it to be like.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` with a table inside the fieldset...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset